# Kotlin distinct() from 2 Dimensional array

Tags: arrays, kotlin

```
fun main() {

    val data = ArrayList<List<String>>()
    
    data.add(listOf("32701", "First"))
    data.add(listOf("32702", "Second"))
    data.add(listOf("32702", "Second"))
    data.add(listOf("32701", "First True"))
    
    println(data.distinct())

}
```

Result :

> [[32701, First], [32702, Second], [32701, First True]]

Question How about removing data `[32701, First]` and get new data with the same value ?

Expected :

> [32702, Second], [32701, First True]]

Comment: `distictBy()` might help: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/distinct-by.html . You may need extra work to keep the "latest" 32701

Comment: I have try with distictBy() but you right, need extra work to keep the "latest", any suggestion?

Comment: Just checking you're aware of the [Map](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-map/index.html) type, and have a good reason for using lists of lists, with the possibility of duplicate ‘keys’, instead…?  (Even then, you might find it easier to use [Pair](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-pair/)s instead of the inner Lists.)

Comment: To keep the latest  - reverse the list before doing `distinctBy`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `distinct()` uses the `equals` methods and comparing the entirety of the list.

You could use `distinctyBy { it.first() }` if you can ensure lists wont be empty

---

#### Edit

In order to get latest value you can:

a) Reverse the list and then call `distinctBy`

```kotlin
yourList
    .reversed() // Now latest values are first in the list
    .distinctBy { it.first() } // first element of list holds the id
```

b) Associate the values into a map of `Map<String, List<String>>` by calling `associateBy { it.first()}` and getting the last value of the map by calling

`val correctResults = map.values.map { valueList -> valueList.last() }`

As a whole would look like:

```kotlin
yourList
    .associateBy { it.first() }
    .values
    .map { valueList -> valueList.last() }
```

Be aware that any of these approaches **IS NOT** dealing with empty lists.

In order to deal with empty lists you could filter them out by just doing

```kotlin
val listsThatAreNotEmpty = yourList.filter { it.isNotEmpty() }
```

Comment: Thanks, I have try this way but the result is `[[32701, First], [32702, Second]]` how to make keep the "latest" 32701 ? So the result is `[32702, Second], [32701, First True]]`

Comment: In order to do that it's not enough to use `distinctBy`. You'll need to either reverse the list with `reverse()` or create a map by calling  `associateBy` and then getting the latest element of the MapEntry

Answer (score 1):

Use a combination of `reversed` and `disinctBy`:

```kotlin
fun main() {
     val Data = ArrayList<List<String>>()
    
    Data.add(listOf("32701", "First"))
    Data.add(listOf("32702", "Second"))
    Data.add(listOf("32702", "Second"))
    Data.add(listOf("32701", "First True"))
    
   
    println(Data.reversed().distinctBy{it[0]} ) 
   // prints [[32701, First True], [32702, Second]]
}
```

You can reverse the result again to get the original relative order.

As mentioned by others, the use of `listOf` is sub-optimal, here is a cleaner version:

```kotlin
data class Item(val id: String, val text: String)

fun distinct(data : List<Item>) = data.reversed().distinctBy{it.id} 

fun main() {
     val data = listOf(
         Item("32701", "First"),
         Item("32702", "Second"),
         Item("32702", "Second"),
         Item("32701", "First True")
     )
   
    println(distinct(data) ) 
   // [Item(id=32701, text=First True), Item(id=32702, text=Second)]
}
```